# When did Abu Dulaf Khazraji ascend Mount Damavand?

Tags: historical-accuracy, accuracy

There are two reported dates for the ascention of Mount Damavand by Abu Dulaf Khazraji.

In [this](https://www.summitpost.org/damavand/150400) site (which Wikipedia is using as a source) and some others it's stated that:

> The earliest recorded ascent of Damavand was made in 905 by Abu Dolaf Kazraji, although others unknown may have preceded him.

But in [this](http://damavandnameh.ir/showT.aspx?Lang=F&ID=735F5D40515E4970585A) one and other sites (in Persian) it's stated that:

> در طي سال هاي 331 -341 (942-952 ميلادي) به شهرهاي مختلف ايران مسافرت و گردش نموده و مشاهداتش را به نگارش درآورده است.

which means (he) traveled to Iran between the years 331 and 341 A.H. (Arabic lunar year) which equals to 942 to 952 A.D.

And before that he was traveling to China and India (also in the site)

Which date is true?

Comment: It is quite common for wrong information to be repeated again and again on the internet. Generally I would not really trust a mountaineering website to be very accurate or torough about historical data. In this case, there is probably a primary source (by Abu Dulaf himself?) somewhere that can be cross-checked. Given that 940s/950s seems to be the accepted period of activity of Abu Dulaf (per google), 905 might just be a mix-up with 950?

Comment: (Some websites also seem to imply that not all of Abu Dulaf's claims about his travels are really plausible, so technically neither of the dates might be true)

Comment: It was quite common for wrong information to be repeated again and again in antiquity as well. Once something wrong was written, every manuscript copy and reference to one of them from then on would repeat it.